# Why doesn't C-3PO recognize his own home planet?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the beginning of Star Wars IV. When C-3PO and R2D2 land on Tatooine, it seems like C-3PO doesn't know where he is?

**Why doesn't C-3PO recognize his home planet?**

Comment: At the end of Episode III, he had his memory wiped.

Answer (score 9):

Because at the end of Episode III, C-3PO had his memory [*wiped*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Memory_wipe/Canon) by Captain Antilles

> “How lovely!” C-3PO exclaimed. “His daughter is the child of Master
>   Anakin and Senator Amidala,” he explained to R2-D2. “I can hardly wait
>   to tell her all about her parents! I’m sure she will be very proud-“
>
> **“Oh, and the protocol droid?” Senator Organa said thoughtfully. “Have
>   its mind wiped.” The captain saluted. “Oh,” said C-3PO. “Oh, dear.”** - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith - Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I was going to put my comment as an answer, but I figured by the time I found the clip to support it there would be at least one answer that had already done it ;)

Comment: If you enjoy canon discontinuities, you can watch this DVD-Extra from "Attack of the Clones" where C-3PO completely undermines the idea that he's had a memory wipe; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrPh8Tlbybc

Comment: Argh! At least now you know what to use instead of those Thor gifs: a ninja with the fastest gun in the west ;-)

Answer (score 3):

At the end of [*Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-3PO#cite_ref-Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_12-1):

> C-3PO and R2-D2 fall into the custody of Bail Organa, who orders that **C-3PO's memories be erased** to protect the twins from their father.

---

Lower down the canon scale, we also have the following quote from the comic [Vader vs. Artoo & Threepio](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vader_vs._Artoo_%26_Threepio):

> Vader: "No… I am your creator!"
>   [...]
>   C-3PO: "Noooo!! You see, sir, shortly after the Jedi were wiped out, my memory was erased. So that could explain why I'm having difficulty verifying your statement."

And in an EU novel, C-3PO was advised by [the silver protocol droid CP-16](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TC-16) to accept a memory wipe if the situation arose:

> C-3PO conferred with a silver protocol droid who warned him that dark times were ahead. He told C-3PO to accept a memory wipe if it was ever offered, as the alternative would be living in confusion as the lines between good and evil were blurred.

Comment: CP-16 exists solely within an EU novel, as far as I'm aware...

Comment: @Richard Edited.